# How can I use JSON data with Angular?

Tags: css, json, angular, typescript

I have some problems about using json with angular.

In my project I generate components.

And I delete spec.ts.

After that I create a file named prod.data.json

```
{
    "products" :
        [
            {
                "sku" : "10",
                "name" : "Laptop Blue Background",
                "saleTag" : false,
                "prodImage" : "img",
                "price" : "210",
                "discountly" : "200",
                "revives" : "3",
                "summary" : "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only",
                "availability" : "In Stock",
                "categori" : "Business",
                "tag" : "Book",
                "share" : {
                        "facebook" : "link",
                        "twitter" : "link",
                        "instagram" : "link",
                        "linkedin" : "link"
                },
```

The json codes format are like that.

And content.companents.ts named file codes are..

```
import prodData from '/Users/obasekin/angular-crash/src/app/prod.data.json';
interface Product {
  sku: Number;
  name: String;
  saleTag: String;
  prodImage: String;
  price: Number;
  discountly: Number;
  revives: Number;
  summary: String;
  availability: String;
  catagori: String;
  tag: String;
  share: {
    facebook: String;
    twitter: String;
    instagram: String;
    linkedin: String;
  };
  description: {
    desSummary: String;
    desList: {
      lineMono: String;
      lineDi: String;
      lineTri: String;
      lineTetra: String;
      linePenta: String;
      lineHexa: String;
    };
  };
}
```

I import the format which is String or Number.

My problem is in this code..

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  products: Product[] = prodData;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

products is have problem in this line

```
products: Product[] = prodData;
```

issues ss here..

[cruser on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jtq1.png)

**Update 1**

I have tsconfig.json

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

Other way problem ss

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CvnM.png)

regards

Comment: I'm sorry I forget mention it. I have in tsconfig.json:  "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true

Comment: try `products: Product[] = prodData.products;`

Comment: I tryed and still same

Answer (score 0):

That's because `prodData` is not an array; it's an object containing a `products` array.

Add the wrapper object to your interface:

```
export interface Inventory {
  products: Product[];
}

export interface Product {
  ...
}
```

Then in your class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  inventory: Invertory = prodData;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get products(): Product[] {
    return this.inventory.products;
  }

}
```

Comment: Now it says "Cannot find name 'Invertory'.ts(2304)"

Comment: Probably an import/export problem, export the interfaces (see my edit), then use `import` statements in your `ContentComponent` (i.e. `import { Inventory, Product } from 'src/app/model/model.ts';`)

Comment: do you mean where should I import "import { Inventory, Product } from 'src/app/model/model.ts';" I mean in which file and I dont have model/model.ts

Comment: Whatever file you have them in

Answer (score 0):

You set the wrong values in the `prod.data.json`. You stored numbers as `string`.

Set them this way:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "sku" : 10,
      "name" : "Laptop Blue Background",
      "saleTag" : false,
      "prodImage" : "img",
      "price" : 210,
      "discountly" : 200,
      "revives" : 3,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a new file named :

> content.interface.ts

in here:

```
export interface IProduct {
    sku: Number;
    name: String;
    saleTag: boolean;
    prodImage: String;
    price: Number;
    discountly: Number;
  }
```

also in:

> content.components.ts

Import both and their paths

```
import prodData from '../(what was ur json file name).json';

import {IProduct} from './content.interface'
```

And I export like that:

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
      products: IProduct[] = prodData.products;
}
```

now everything is work way well..